# How to animate my data?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, animation

I would like to point out that I only have basic experience with Mathematica. If this is a dumb question, I apologize in advance. Anyways, I am trying to make a density plot of an interpolation of data onto a shape with varying data points. So far, I have the region defined:

```
  ContourStyle -> White, Contours -> {1/2, 1}, 
  ContourShading -> {White, None}]; 
st = ContourPlot[(x^2)/4 + (y^2)/9, {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 3}, 
  ContourStyle -> White, Contours -> {1/2, 1}, 
  ContourShading -> {White, None}]
```

I also have the interpolation function defined:

```
if = Interpolation[{{-2, 0, Extract[s, {1, 2, 6}]}, {-1, 2.5, 
     Extract[s, {1, 2, 7}]}, {1, 2.5, Extract[s, {1, 2, 8}]}, {2, 0, 
     Extract[s, {1, 2, 9}]}}, InterpolationOrder -> All];  
tt = DensityPlot[if[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 3}];
```

Then to show it:

```
Show[tt, st]
```

However, my question now is how can I make this plot a function of the parameter t. This is my attempt.

```
if[t_] = Interpolation[{{-2, 0, Extract[s, {1, t+1, 6}]}, {-1, 2.5, 
     Extract[s, {1, t+1, 7}]}, {1, 2.5, Extract[s, {1, t+1, 8}]}, {2, 0, 
     Extract[s, {1, t+1, 9}]}}, InterpolationOrder -> All];
```

But then, could I make `tt[t_]`? Because when I tried, I got the message "Could not combine the graphics objects in Show" upon entering `tt[2]`. How can I fix this so that I can use `Manipulate[]` or `Animate[]`? Thanks for the help.

Comment: `tt` is a graphics object because you have it defined as a `DensityPlot`.

Comment: In your post there is an object, s, that is not defined. There is also an unknown object, st. I recommend you to post these. If they are large, post some minimal examples, this is even better.  This will enable us to understand what is it about.